# Value from subscription is not saved outside of subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an Angular application and i want to save a set of data in a service(located in my shared module) for easy access. I made that data to be an rxjs Subject, so i could always have the latest information.

When i try to retrieve the data from component X, that imports the shared module (with the service, i suppose -- service is provided in SharedModule) any variable that I declared in the class, be it object with properties or simple Boolean, after the subscription ends, the value does not remain.

I saw that it worked if the component and service are part of the same feature module, but it weirdly stops if they are not.

```
export class X implements OnInit {
   public valueIWantToChange;

constructor(private service: Service) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.service.dataSubject.subscribe(res => {
      this.valueIWantToChange = res;
      console.log(this.valueIWantToChange) // will show the correct value
})
} //value will be lost here

}

test() { //this is called on a test button just to check the value
   console.log(this.valueIWantToChange); // element is empty
}

---------------------------------
export class Service {

data = new Subject();
dataSubject = this.data.asObservabel();

changeData(value) {
    this.data.next(value); 
}
 }
```

When i click on Test button in html, i expect the value to be the one from the service, but that is not happening.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A `Subject` needs to emit a value _after_ the observer has subscribed. If you want the latest value to be re-emitted when new observers subscribe, try using a `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: As will explained, Subject doesn't keep the value, you need to use `BehvaiorSubject`

Comment: Ty so much guys, that make perfect sense. I already had another subscriber listening to that observable, that would explain why my value was never saved. Tried with BehaviorSubject and it seems to work fine! 

Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Subject` needs to emit a value *after* the observer has subscribed. If you want the latest value to be re-emitted when new observers subscribe, try using a `BehaviorSubject`.